# Help with the functional equation $f(x - f(y)) = f(f(y)) + 2 x f(y) + f(x) - 1$

Tags: functional-equations

I am asked to find all $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x - f(y)) = f(f(y)) + 2 x f(y) + f(x) - 1$, which I solved and got that $f(x) = 1 - x^2$ -- a correct solution and everything.

What puzzles me is how do I find *all* solutions. I wrote that all functions $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which map in the same way as $f$ are solutions, but is there something I'm missing here?

Have an awesome day, all of you.

Comment: How are $x$ and $y$ related? If they have no relation then you could just as well put $k=f(y)$ and write $$f(x-k)=f(k)+2x\ k+f(x)-1$$

Comment: I had to do something like that while solving, and I came to a simple linear equation.

Could I perhaps start off by taking the inverse function of both sides? I don't think I'd be able to solve such an equation, though.

Comment: The functional equation in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1573698/229831) post differes with the current one a little bit, but the exact same method can be used here to show that $f(x)=1-x^2$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wrote $f:\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\R\rightarrow\R$ I think it is fair to assume that the domain of the function is all of $\R$. Now, let $A=f(\R)$ be the codomain of the function. For any $k\in A$ we then have
$$
f(x-k)=f(k)+2x\ k+f(x)-1
$$

### Not a bounded function

First note that $f$ cannot be a bounded function for if $A\subseteq[-M,M]$ and $k\in A$ we get
$$
M\geq |f(x-k)|=|f(k)+2x\ k+f(x)-1|\geq |2x\ k-1|-2M
$$
so then we see that $|2x\ k-1|\leq 3M$ which is impossible since $2x\ k$ is not bounded unless $k=0$. Of course then we must also check that $A=\{0\}$ is impossible, but that is directly seen from
$$
f(x)=f(x-0)=f(0)+2x\cdot 0+f(x)-1
$$
implying that $f(0)=1$ thus contradicting $A=\{0\}$. It follows that $f$ must be unbounded. This tells us that $A$ must contain infinitely many function values. In particular $f$ cannot be a constant function.

### Analyzing if codomain contains zero

If $0\in A$ it follows as stated above that $f(0)=1$. Now for any $k$ in the infinite set $A$ we then have
$$
1=f(k-k)=2 f(k)+2k^2-1\\
\iff\\
f(k)=1-k^2
$$
so in this case $f$ acts exactly like the function you proposed on the set $A$.

If we also know (I do not know if we do) that $f$ is a polynomial expression this then implies that $1-x^2-f(x)$ is a polynomial having all elements of $A$ as roots so it follows that this is the zero polynomial and thus $f(x)=1-x^2$ in that case.

### If codomain does not contain zero

So what happens if $A$ does not contain zero. Then we cannot be certain that $f(0)=1$. Then define $f(0)=2q+1$ and let us see what happens when analyzing this. We then have for $k\in A$ that
$$
2q+1=f(k-k)=2 f(k)+2k^2-1\\
\iff\\
f(k)=(q+1)-k^2
$$
so if again we assume $f$ to be a polynomial it follows that $f(x)=(q+1)-x^2$. But then we must have $q<-1$ [and thus $f(0)=2q+1<-1$] for otherwise $f$ does have zeros. But if we plug this $f$ into the functional equation and expand both sides we see that this is impossible.

### Conclusion:

If $f$ is a polynomial expression then $f(x)=1-x^2$ is the unique solution to the functional equation. I do not know whether it be possible for $f$ NOT to be a polynomial but still satisfying the equation.

Comment: Hi **String**,

I understand all of this (and have something very similar in my solution); but, are there any functions **other** than $f(x) = 1 - x^2$ which satisfy the given criterion?

Thanks.