# Can we assume $ f ( y ) = 0 $ in solving the functional equation $ f \big( x - f ( y ) \big) = f \big( f ( y ) \big) + x f ( y ) + f ( x ) - 1 $?

Tags: functional-equations

Here's a problem from one of my books. I believe it's not really a **compete solution**.

> **Problem.** Determine all functions $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that
> $$ f \big( x - f ( y ) \big) = f \big( f ( y ) \big) + x f ( y ) + f ( x ) - 1 \tag i \label i $$
> for all $ x , y \in \mathbb R $.
>
> **Solution.** Put $ x = f ( y ) = 0 $ in Eq. \eqref{i}. Then
> $$ f ( 0 ) = f ( 0 ) + 0 + f ( 0 ) - 1 \text ; $$
> $$ \therefore \ f ( 0 ) = 1 \text . $$
> Again, put $ x = f ( y ) = \lambda $ in Eq. \eqref{i}. Then
> $$ f ( 0 ) = f ( \lambda ) + \lambda ^ 2 + f ( \lambda ) - 1 \text ; $$
> $$ \implies 1 = 2 f ( \lambda ) + \lambda ^ 2 - 1 \text ; $$
> $$ \therefore \ f ( \lambda ) = \frac { 2 - \lambda ^ 2 } 2 = 1 - \frac { \lambda ^ 2 } 2 \text . $$
> Hence, $ f ( x ) = 1 - \frac { x ^ 2 } 2 $ is the unique function.

In the opening line of the solution, it assumes that $ f ( y ) = 0 $ exists. But we don't really know if it's a surjective function. So, even if we assume such and prove, then, as the question demands ***"all possible functions that satisfy …"***, I believe there's another part of the problem assuming that no such $ y $ exists for which $ f ( y ) = 0 $ which may be proved or disproved, but not left unattempted.

Right?

Comment: Which book${}$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah, you may please ignore that. It's not really a good book 

Comment: So, since we don't really know if such $y$ exists, there should be another part of the solution, right?

Comment: There **may** exist a function for which $f(a)\neq 0$ for any $a$ but still satisfies the FE.

Comment: Hello! See [Problem 16 here](http://imomath.com/index.php?options=341&lmm=0).

Comment: [Same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1573698/229831).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.  In fact, there is another error in the solution as well: it only shows that $f(\lambda)=1-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}$ under the assumption that $\lambda=f(y)$ for some $y$.  So this solution really is only valid if you know $f$ is surjective (which is in fact not possible, since the function $f(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ is not surjective!).

A correct solution requires a much more careful analysis to show the range of $f$ must be large enough that you can in fact conclude $f(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ for all $x$.  As Rohan commented, you can find a correct solution [here](http://imomath.com/index.php?options=341&lmm=0) (Problem 16).

Answer (score 0):

I also don't see why we can assume there exists $y$ such that $f(y)=0 .$

Let $x=2f(y).$ Then $$f(f(y))=f(2f(y)-f(y))=f(x-f(y))=f(f(y))+xf(y)+f(x)-1$$ which simplifies to $$0=xf(y)+f(x)-1$$ which, with $f(y)=x/2,$ gives $$0=x^2/2+f(x)-1.$$ So $f(x)=1-x^2/2$ whenever $x\in \{2f(y):y\in \Bbb R\}.$

It's very late for me. Perhaps someone else is willing to finish this:  What if $x\not \in \{2f(y): y\in \Bbb R\}$?

Comment: I believe $x\in \{2f(y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ as the function is $\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$

Comment: The notation $f:A\to B$ does not mean that $f$ is surjective  onto $B$.

Comment: Yes, but $x$ whichever​ value $2f(y)$ can take, we can say that $x$ can take all such values. That's what I meant. Nothing related to surjection. At the end of your answer you mentioned **"what if $x\not\in \{ 2 f(y) : y \in \mathbb{R}\}$"**. Basically I wanted to say that there won't be any case when $x\not \in\{\cdots\}$. I believe $x$ always $\in$ $\{\cdots\}$

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.